# Run code on WPF form close

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I automatically run some code when a WPF form is closed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just attach an event handler to [Window.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) for your form.

It's also possible to do this in a more MVVM-friendly approach by creating a custom ICommand, and having it fire based off the event.  Here is a [blog post describing this approach](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html).

Once you've done that, you can have a command on your ViewModel that will fire when the form closes.