# Execute code when a WPF closes

Tags: wpf, event-handling, execute

I am not familiar with using event handlers, and I was wondering if anyone had or could direct me to some code that shows how to use an event handler that will execute code on the Close/Closed event?

I know this can be done because of this answered question:

[Run code on WPF form close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374528/run-code-on-wpf-form-close)

But I need some direction.

Thank you =)

Comment: Look here and use `OnExit` instead of `OnStartup`. http://manaspatnaik.com/blog/index.php/technology/wpf/event-handling-in-wpf/193

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's just this XAML

```
<Window ... Closing="Window_Closing" Closed="Window_Closed">
    ...
</Window>
```

and code for both the `Closing` and `Closed` events

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 26):

If you want to do it all from code behind put this in your windows .cs file

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Closed += new EventHandler(MainWindow_Closed);
        }

        void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Put your close code here
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do part in xaml and part in code behind do this in xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closed="MainWindow_Closed">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this in .cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Put your close code here
        }
    }
}
```

The above to examples you can apply to any form in a xaml app.  You can have multiple forms.  If you want to apply code for the entire application exit process modify your app.xaml.cs file to this

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Put your special code here
            }
            finally
            {
                base.OnExit(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the OnExit function in App.Xaml.cs like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        //do your things
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "OnExit()" method is not showing up in the intellisense and I know I have the correct using statement because MSDN says it's in the System.Windows namespace. Any ideas?

Comment: Excactly, what I needed. @Stylzs05: It is an old question, but for those who come here: intellisense is kicking in, if you write ```protected override  ``` to declare the method.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using C# on Microsoft Visual Studio, the following worked for me.

In your Window.cs file

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Name_Space
{
    public partial class Window : Form
    {

        public Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           //...
        }

        private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //...
        }

        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Your code goes here...!
        }
    }
}
```

In your Window.Designer.cs file add this line to the following method

```
    ...
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {

            ...

            // 
            // Window
            // 
            ...

            this.Closed += new System.EventHandler(this.Window_Closed); // <-- add this line
         }

    ...
```

Comment: This appears to be for Windows Forms, the question is about WPF.