# how to refresh a datagrid in c# wpf frequently

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a data grid using wpf,c#.
A separate window is used to insert data into data grid .After clicking save button the data grid is not updating .If we close or refresh the window the grid will update.

```html
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgTrnDetails"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="380" Width="1104"  >

            <DataGrid.FontSize>
                16
            </DataGrid.FontSize>
            <DataGrid.FontFamily>
                <FontFamily>Arial</FontFamily>
            </DataGrid.FontFamily>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TRN Number" Binding="{Binding TRNNO}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier" Binding="{Binding Supplier}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Customer}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehicle" Binding="{Binding Vehicle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Driver" Binding="{Binding Driver}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="AddButton" Content="Edit" Click="btnEditTrn_Click"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: bind your data to datagrid again

Comment: To get the grid refreshed immediatly, you need to modify the data structure the grid is bound to. Probably an event aggregator would be usefull

Comment: how do you insert data? binding or Items.Add()? please add some of your code

Comment: You definitely want to bind your data. use an observable collection.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a closed event for your seperate window as you can see in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033551/wpf-window-closed-event-usage)

Then in the closed event you need to do that:

```
dgTrnDetails.ItemSource = yourItemSource;
```