# How to enable button on Main Window when secondary window is closing or get closed? - WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have two windows. Main Window & Window1.

On Main Window, there is a button1. When it is clicked, it gets disabled and open Window1. But i want to enable button1 on Main Window when Window1 is closing or get closed.

Comment: instead of tagging this for c# you should include a tag for `wpf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create A Public Button in Window1

```
public Button mainBtn ;
```

on mainWindow  in the button click event

```
private void button_click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e){
Window1 win = new Window1();
this.button.IsEnabled = false; 
win.mainBtn = this.button;
win.Show();
}
```

add on closing event to Window1

```
   private void Window_closing(object sender , CancelEventArgs e){
    mainBtn.IsEnabled = true; 
}
```

the idea is to pass the MainWindow Button to the Window1 Button 
then you can control it as like you want .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using WinForms. In that case you have an event handler for the click on button1:

```
private void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // show window 1
}
```

Now there are two methods to show a Form. You can show it as a modeless dialog box or as a modal dialog box.

- Modal dialog boxes, which require the user to respond before continuing the program
- Modeless dialog boxes, which stay on the screen and are available for use at any time but permit other user activities

Most dialog boxes you see are Modal: If you press file save, you'll have to finish the Save-File-Dialog box before you can continue editing.

The modal dialog box is the easiest
 - Show them using using Form.ShowDialog.
 - ShowDialog returns when the form is closed.

If you use a modal dialog box your code would look sequential:

```
private void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    using (Window1 window1 = new Window1())
    {
        // if needed window1.SetValues...
        var dlgResult = window1.ShowDialog(this);
        // if here, window 1 is closed
        if (dlgResult = DialogResult.OK)
        {   // ok button pressed
            // if needed: window1 read resulting values
        }
     }  // because of using window 1 automatically disposed
}
```

However if window1 is shown as a modeless dialog box, window1 will have to tell others that it is closed. Use event Form.Closed:

```
private Window1 window1 = null;
private void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
   if (this.window1 != null) return; // window1 already shown

   this.window1 = new Window1())
   this.window1.Closing += this.OnFormClosed;
}

private void OnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("window1 closed");
    if (this.window1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // process dialog results
    }
    this.window1.Dispose();
    this.window1 = null;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that changes your answer but his question refers to WPF.

Comment: No, Its not WinForms. As i mentioned in my question. I want to do this in WPF.

Comment: On the other hand, setting an event handler on the Closing and/or on the Closed event of the popup window would be quite similar in WPF, I would think (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018308/execute-code-when-a-wpf-closes).

Answer (score 0):

Data Binding is the strongest tool in WPF:
Add the button and bind the IsEnabled property to a public property in your view model or code behind. In the secondary window  - when closing - update the property to reflect the new state.

Do not forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Can you write some code. I'm beginner in programming so i can't understand what you say.