# How main WPF window knows when secondary WPF window is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I faced a problem. I have two WPF windows in my project and I open the second WPF window by pressing the button on the main WPF window. But when I close the second window I need the first window to know that this happened and to do some action. How do I make this? I tried isLoaded and Application.Current.Windows, but both of them didn't work as I needed. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run code on WPF form close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374528/run-code-on-wpf-form-close)

Comment: No, the event handler will work in the same event tree, but I need to cross the two windows, two event trees.

Comment: What is an "event tree"? FYI: The answer you accepted is no different than the suggestion I linked to (other than it has code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this.

```
   public void CreateNewWindow()
   {
       Window wind=new Window();
       wind.Closing+=yourClosingHandler;
   }



   void yourClosingHandler(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   {
     //do some staff
   }
```