# Logout everytime i close the form application C# WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

So, I am kind of beginner in WCF and I've build a windows form chat application that show user logged in once they login but i want to make logout even if the user cross (X) close the form directly. so How can i do that.. Thank You.

Comment: Use [Window.Closing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374528/run-code-on-wpf-form-close)

Basically you process logout on that event handler Window.Closed

Answer (score 1):

I would make a method Logout and excecute it i the Window.Closed event and also implement it in the Logout button.Clicket .